# How to write $x$ is not related to $y$ in binary relations?

Tags: notation, relations

I am trying to prove a relation is not transivitive. So I start with  $xRy$ and $yRz$. Then I want to write: "But, $x$ doesn't relate to $z$." How do I write that mathematically?

Comment: $(x,y) \in R \text { and } (y,z) \in R \text { and } (x,z) \notin R$.

Comment: Or, $\lnot xRz$.

Comment: If you use $\sim$ for your relation, then $x \not \sim y$ is standard.

Comment: Could even write $\require{cancel} x \cancel{R} y$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. On this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: Also, If you find any of the answers to a question useful, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers that are *and* [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. If you don't, it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer combining the comments:

You could write:

- $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$, but $(x,z)\notin R$.
- $xRy$ and $yRz$, but $\neg (xRz)$.
- $xRy$ and $yRz$, but $\require{cancel} x \cancel{R} y$.
- $x$ relates to $y$ and $y$ relates to $z$, but $x$ does not relate to $z$.

I added that last one because you ended your question with "*How do I write that mathematically?*" To *write something mathematically* does not mean *use crazy symbols*. If something is written **clearly**, **precisely** and **unambiguously**, then it is written *mathematically*.

The only reason to use symbols is to save space, which can make things easier to read (though not necessarily). The validity of a statement does not change if you choose to use words in stead of symbols.

Comment: +1 for "use words"!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $R$ is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that x is related to $y$

Thus  $$(x,y) \in R \text { and } (y,z) \in R,  \text { but } (x,z) \notin R$$ is a mathematically correct way to express your idea.